# How to call custom events of Dialogflow, by REST api end point?

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, dialogflow-es, chatbot, api-ai

I want to use custom events in Dialogflow to invoke an event (Welcome event) from my ionic application. I need to call an end point as described in [link](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events/custom-events), I am calling the same from postman but getting error below -

```
{
"code": 401, 
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED", 
"message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."
}
```

I am putting correct access token, projectId, Intent id of my agent.
Please let me know, If there are other way to call Dialogflow welcome event from Ionic app. It would be great.

Comment: It doesn't _sound_ like you're using the correct access token. Can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23508913) to show the code you're using, discuss how you're building the access token, etc?

Comment: try using dialogflow-nodejs if u work it with nodejs, it might help u